# jQuery Mobile Changing Viewport Parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, viewport

In my mobile site, I have the viewport meta tag set as:

```
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=5,user-scalable=yes" name="viewport">
```

When I look at the source of the page in a browser (any browser, any device), I see the 'content' parameter has been altered to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=5,user-scalable=yes,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Note the additional parameters in 'content'. JQM seems to be tacking on the "maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" values at runtime. Anybody know how to get JQM to stop this annoyance? It's effect is that one cannot pinch/zoom the site at all.

UPDATE: I found a variation of the following code on a post in the jQuery forum, which basically resets the viewport's 'content' parameter to what it should be:

```
<script>
var fixedPageMeta = "width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=5,user-scalable=yes";
jQuery('[data-role=page]').live('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    jQuery('#viewportMeta').attr("content", fixedPageMeta); 
});
</script>
```

I can see that the 'content' parameter is now correct in the source of the page, however, still can't pinch/zoom. Anyone have any suggestions?